# ios - UIActivityIndicatorView with storyboard not behaving correctly in the controller

Tags: ios, ios5, uiactivityindicatorview

I put a UIActivityIndicatorView on my storyboard screen and from the storyboard screen I dragged the UIActivityIndicatorView to the .h file of my controller and it created this in my .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

But when I started working in the .m file, it didn't place the property there automatically, and when I tried to put this in there:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

which gave the error

```
Illigal declaration of property in the continuation class xyz, property must be readWrite...
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? And how do I fix it? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redeclare a property in a class continuation, it is illegal to change the memory qualifiers associated with it, it is only possible to go from readonly to readwrite (and vice versa, though I don't see why anyone would want to do it).  Either remove the weak, or the retained outlet, and leave just one.

Also, properties are not "placed" in classes for you "automatically."  If you need to access a property on an object, dot or message syntax will work just fine.

Comment: I think I just didn't realize the difference between weak/retained.  Which should it be? I tried each, but they did not work.

Comment: IBOutlets that are not considered "Top-Level" (top-most superview, navigation controllers), are supposed to have the weak or assign qualifier associated with them.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. Also, would you know why the spinner appears by default and does not spin? I thought I was supposed to make it appear/disappear in the code.  Am I wrong about that?